# Failing to detect all parallel (narrow) rectangles [opencv]

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

- I am working to detect the individual lines/rectangles in a barcode. They are different widths but equivalent height (the height of the barcode itself).
- The issue i'm running into is although the rectangles appear to be identical and sit parallel to eachother I cannot manage to detect them all unless changing the image I am scanning to make the narrowest of the rectangles wider. Any suggestions?
- I've tried a few different setups but here is my current:

```py
    blur = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 11, 21)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.001 * perimeter, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            x = cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,250,12),1)
```

Here is the resulting image (cut to remove contained information) I am trying to detect *all* outer bars of the barcode.

[image: resulting pdf417 image]

[image: Base Image]

Comment: Are you trying to detect the rectangles individually?

Comment: Yes. I want to read the barcode and i'm thinking currently I'll have to template it into a grid system of binary white/black boxes. However I need to determine the L/W width of each"box". The easiest way to do this I can think of is to locate the constant 7 rectangles of same height and minimum width. The larger full black rectangles are *7 and *8 the minimum width. Visual here: https://www.morovia.com/manuals/PDF417-Font-ware-Writer-SDK-4/images/PDF417-Symbol-Anatomy-96dpi.png

Open to other suggestions on how to read (not detect) a barcode

Comment: Alternatively, each larger region of a row indicator or data code-word is split into 17 regions width wise. It begins with a solid black column and ends with a "space" or solid white column of 1/17th width

Comment: I see now I would have less margin of error detecting the full regions (fig.1) and dividing them by 17 (or 18 at stop) rather than avg the minimum width columns. fig.1: https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/PDF417-sections-4-1000x337.png

Though I still am not sure why detecting the rectangles originally failed.

Comment: Are you doing this because you need to or for fun? Because it seems there are potentially some other PDF417 scanners out there on the web. What robustness level are you looking to achieve? Only digital images, or real images too? Some minor notes about your current implementation: the approx poly method is not at all reliable for getting rectangular detections, you'd have better luck just checking the aspect ratio of the height/width of the contour. I would go with a "radon transform" approach to detect the barcode location.

Comment: The radon or hough transforms calculate an integral rotating through the image. The general idea of this can be used to detect text orientation, for example. But the applicability with this example is to simply take the integral (i.e. the sum) of the image in each column. You'll have the maximum spikes wherever the image is all white vertically. This gives a pretty decent way to detect lines; ultimately this is also what the hough transform does but over all possible angles, so that may be more generalizable. As an aside, the blurring in your preproccesing really ruins your binary image.

Comment: Just for fun but i'd like to share the finished scanner openly & in python which doesn't seem to have reliable free options.

I will check out the radon transform. Though I might have to approach this differently if the goal is to find the width/height accurately for each barcode module. I'll comment back when I see where this gets me & of course i'm open to barcode decoding alg suggestions... Most content is simply locating them not decoding.  


>> I want to perform on digital & real images

Comment: I thought the blurring was probably a bad move but since I pulled this code region from another post somewhere I opted to leave it in. Appreciate the help thus far ~